# Automatically switching between two running programs

Tags: windows, input, automation, keyboard

Because I really don't know a lot about this domain of programming, it might be clearer for me to explain what I would do if I were to input myself the commands I want to automatize (i.e. I just launch a script and all this procedure should be done automatically).

1. Lauch both the Game and the Task.
2. Start a game of the Game and immediately pause it.
3. Alt tab to the task.
4. Do it until a point determined in the program. At which point I am
   told to switch to the game.
5. Alt tab to the game
6. Unpause it and start a clockwatch.
7. When the clockwatch reaches X minutes (X determined in advance),
   pause the game.
8. Alt tab to the task.
9. Repeat steps 4-7 N number of times.

I have no idea whether it is possible or what tools to use. I understood that a simple bash file won't be enough and I might need to use a "fake keyboard" program to force some inputs (such as "space bar" to pause the game). But I have no idea how to coordinate all of that.

Thanks in advance for any help. Even telling me it's not possible is an acceptable answer :)

EDIT : Edited the list for clarity

Comment: Why did you tag both `bash` and `windows` ? are you using bash on ubuntu on windows ? Also, your question is waaaaay too vague to be answered in one go. Please do some research and refine it. A quick google search suggested using `autoit` for macros on windows, or `wmctrl` and `xdotool` on linux. Have a look at those tools.

Comment: It may be possible, using "events injectors", but somehow (after reading your question) I feel that explaining it to you is weeeeell beyond your knowledge. Just a small indication, WINDOWS and BASH are not a standard combination.

Comment: @Aserre, interesting we both thought more or less the same and selected to use a _stretched_ word to express ourselves.

Comment: Sorry for windows and bash... I was thinking about batch files and got confused I guess. My bad.
I'll be using this on windows so I should have left out bash.

Comment: @Aserre : As you suggested (and it's true) this is weeeell beyond my knowledge which is why I posted it here. Because simply knowing whether it's possible or not would take me a lot of time and I can start digging myself knowing it's not a deadend...

Comment: @user2532666 I didn't say it was weeeeell beyond your knowledge, only that your question was waaaaay too vague ^^ However, doing such automation is absolutely feasable. 2 popular programs (among others) address this type of issue on windows, `autoit` and `autohotkey`. `autohotkey` is said to be easier to learn, and there are plenty of tutorials on the web (like [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) or [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/93020-switching-active-windows-and-sending-a-keystroke/), more related to your need but more advanced)

Comment: @Aserre I'll be careful about my next questions then. Where would you suggest I'd post such questions next time? Reddit, someplace else?  Thanks a lot for your replies, I've been able to do what I wanted to do using AutoHotKey.

Comment: @user2532666 You could have asked your question here, the problem is that you need to ask questions that are clear and that address one specific issue. Also, do some research before asking a question. Here, you just listed all of your problems all at once, without having tried naything beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what information you have given, it is difficult to tell whether the complete process can be automated, but there are tools like [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) which you can use to write scripts to automate desktop applications.

A simple script in autohotkey to start a program "Notepad", another program "Calculater", and switch back to "Notepad" and write "Hello World!" in it.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
Run "C:\Windows:\Notepad.exe"
Run "calc.exe"
WinActivate, Notepad
Send, Hello World!
```

The above is a very simple script. It does not activate the specific notepad window you want if multiple notepad windows are open. However, that can be automated too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion of AutoHotKey, it worked exactly as I wanted.